# How to get element sequentially from a xml file to java

Tags: java, xml

I have an XML file which contains some attributes and their types and also id.Now i have used apache commons configuration to read them from that XML and i am showing the output in the console from where i have to use the attributes for a database.So the problem is that i am getting all the values from that XML but the values are not coming in order..i.e

```
 <records name="">
<tag id = "1" name= "studentId" type="String"/>
<tag id = "2" name= "StudentName" type= "String"/>
<tag id = "3" name= "StudentType" type= "String"/>
<tag id = "4" name= "recordType" type= "String"/>
.....
```

This is the structure of the xml but when i am running my program i am not getting values sequentially i.e values are not coming in order.But i need the values in order.My code is here

```
public class uu {



public static void main(String[] args)  {


    FmtConfig config = null;
    try {
        config = FmtConfig.instance();
    } catch (ConfigurationException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Records record = config.getRecord();
    System.out.println(record.getName());

  for(String tagName : record.getAllTags().keySet()){
      com.etl.core.model.fmtg.Tag t = record.getAllTags().get(tagName);

     System.out.println("id : "+t.getId()+" name : "+t.getName()+" type : "+t.getType());


    }
```

How i can get values in order someone please help....

Comment: What is your end goal here? Why do you need the tags in order?

Comment: these are sort of metadatas i need to adjust the data with these metadata and need to insert into a table

Comment: I don't really understand how you are using commons config - as you don't show us that. What I do see is a suspicious call to `keySet()`. This looks like `Map.keySet()` which _makes no guarantees as to the order of the map_ if you are using a  [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet%28%29).

Comment: @Boris the Spider what portion of my code you need to solve this???

Comment: If you are indeed using a `HashMap` then simply replace it with a `LinkedHashMap` and it should solve the iteration order issue. I would also recommend you read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet%28%29) - looping over keys and calling `get` for each is very inefficient.